# ExpandaleListView Scrolling in android

Tags: android, scroll, expandablelistview

I am using an expandable listview in android. My layout has a exapndablelistview now the problem is explained with the 3 images below.

#### First Image:

[image: This is my first image that i get when the activity starts. It shows all the parents in the listview]

#### Second Image:

[image: Now when i expand my parent view and the child view is shown it shows from the middle of the child views. Like i have 10 children in one parent then i shall the childview from 5th child and not the first child (I am getting all 10 children) that is below the parent. I have to scroll above to view the first child and parent of that child.]

#### Third Image:

[image: In this image i had to scroll above to view the parent and the first child below the parent.]

My first image that i get when the activity starts. It shows all the parents in the listview

In 2nd Image when i expand my parent view and the child view is shown it shows from the middle of the child views. Like i have 10 children in one parent then i shall the childview from 5th child and not the first child (I am getting all 10 children) that is below the parent. I have to scroll above to view the first child and parent of that child.

In 3rd image i had to scroll above to view the parent and the first child below the parent.

My question is how can i show the expanded listview from the parent that is expanded followed by its children not from the middle of its children??